# Programmatically set the value of a block in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming, drupal-blocks

Can we programmatically set the value of a block in drupal?? We could do that via the admin section, but I am looking to see if there is a way, where we could programmatically say that

```
if($block=="sidebar") {
// do this
}
```

I could then put this in a preprocess node hook or in a block hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using **hook_block()** and setting **($op = "view")** ?!

More info here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_block/6

Comment: but when I have a function mymodule_block, it is not being fired? Can we echo a statement and add an exit, to verify it the hook is firing?

Comment: Kindly copy and paste the whole code in your hook implementation. I need to have a closer look.